# Fetched data shows undefined in first render

Tags: reactjs, next.js, fetch, fetch-api, swr

UPDATE:
The data is coming properly, and there is no any undefined in the component base. But inside the function, the data doesn't update itself. It's always undefined. I also tried to send the data as argument, it didn't work.
I tried useCallback again, didn't work as well.

I have a page includes some components. When I click a button, a Modal shows up. Whenever I open the Modal, I am getting data from server by using SWR. The problem I am facing is whenever I click a button inside the Modal, the data fetches again and again which is not good. I just want to fetch data only when I open the Modal.

Because of this problem, one function in the Modal doesn't work. When I click a button, it runs the function with `undefined` instead of normal fetched data - array of objects -

I tried to use `useCallback` with dependencies, and it didn't work.

I also tried to create a new state and set the data in it like below, but it didn't work again;

```
useEffect(() => {
if(folders){
   setData(folders)
}
},[folders])
```

The codes I use for fetching data are;

import useSWR from 'swr';

```
export default function useFoldersAndDocuments() {
  const fetcher = (url: string) => fetch(url).then((r) => r.json());

  const { data: folders, error: foldersError } = useSWR(
    '/api/folders',
    fetcher
  );
  const { data: documents, error: documentsError } = useSWR(
    '/api/documents',
    fetcher
  );

  return { documents, folders };
}
```

and the function is;

```
function expandGroupedListItem(id: string) {
    console.log(selectedItemIds, 'bfdbfd');

    const currentFolder = folders?.filter((a) => a.id === id);

    if (!selectedItemIds.includes(id)) {
      setSelectedItemIds((prev) => [...prev, id]);
    }

    if (currentFolder && currentFolder[0]?.parentFolder !== null) {
      expandGroupedListItem(currentFolder[0]?.parentFolder);
    }
  }
```

currentFolder is always undefined.

Is there any solution for this problem?

Here is the console.log. `This is folders` firstly shows undefined then shows the data.

[image]

I also render the component like this, but still doesn't work.

```
if (!folders) {
    return null;
  }
```

Comment: Have you confirmed that you are definitely getting data, and getting it in the correct format, from your fetch request?

Comment: Yes I am getting correct data, but in the first render it shows me undefined and then it shows me the normal data.

Comment: I would suggest adding a loader overlay that is rendered conditionally based on the state of the variable where you are storing the result of your fetch (`folders` I believe?). A check for whether the value is undefined or null should be sufficient, as JS considers undefined as null in a lot of circumstances.

Comment: Thank you, I will try it. And I added a new picture showing my console.

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work.

Comment: Can you update your question with your latest attempt?

Comment: I added a condition to render the component, but it didn't work. I added what I did on my question. Thank you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250678/discussion-between-stitt-and-ozan-bilgic).